# Making navigation overlay disappear when pages clicked

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, overlay, nav

Im using a CSS navigation overlay menu, code below

When you click on the navigation menu and select which page you want to go to the overlay stays and does not disappear..

If i link it to another html page it works fine, but as i have all my pages on one page i'm linking it through href to a div like (href="#about")

Any idea how i can make the overlay menu hide once you click on your navigation pages?

Any help much appreciated, thank you

---

```
    <nav id="menu">

        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-nav"/>
        <label id="toggle-nav-label" for="toggle-nav"></label>

        <div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>



a { text-decoration: none; }
    a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

    li { list-style: none; }


    #menu .box {
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        background: black;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    #menu ul {
        position: relative;
        top: 20%;
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
        -moz-transform: scale(2);
        -ms-transform: scale(2);
        transform: scale(2);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    #menu li { 
        margin: 60px;
    }

    #menu li a {
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #fff;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
        -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

    #menu li a:hover { border-color: #fff; }

    #menu li a i { 
        margin-right: 5px; 
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    #toggle-nav-label {
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 30px;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 500;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #toggle-nav { display: none; }

    #toggle-nav:checked ~ .box { 
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 400;
    }

    #toggle-nav:checked ~ .box ul {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    #toggle-nav:checked ~ #toggle-nav-label { 
        color: white;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: small improvements? sorry i was editing the question when you read it as i didnt place any of the code there

Comment: sorry, that was intended to be a comment to my edit..

Comment: You may want to add a demo.  Or add some text or an icon into your label so that we can see something when we try to run the code.

Comment: [codepen](http://codepen.io/boxabrain/pen/sdzcf) thats the demo there

Comment: Thank you for the demo.  I've updated my answer and codepen to reflect your needs.

Comment: If the answer works then it's usually appreciated if you accept it as an answer.  Feel free to hold off on this one for a while to see if anything better comes up, but I know that DD would love random rep from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232616/fancybox-one-image-that-contains-more-images) over a year ago.  Rep is addicting....

Comment: Just got back to my own portfolio now, updated the code with the adjustments you made, works a treat, haven't tested it all on browsers yet, will do it once i've hosted it.. just credited you and DD for both your answers, sorry i took some time in doing it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest answer is to simply uncheck the checkbox using javascript ... but that kinda defeats the purpose of a checkbox hack doesn't it.  I can't think of another way other than to simply make the user click the label again to close the menu.  Kinda ruins the effect you're going for though.  In case nothing better comes up here is a quick javascript solution:

```
window.onload = function() {

 // Add a listener for any clicks on the menu
 document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('click', function(edit) {
    var targetName = event.target.tagName;

    // Make sure that the element being clicked is a link or an icon
    if (targetName !== 'A' && targetName !== 'I') {
      return;
    }
    // Uncheck the checkbox
    document.getElementById('toggle-nav').checked = false;
  });
}
```

And a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGrrrB).  If you want to allow the user to close the menu by clicking anywhere you could add `&& targetName !== 'DIV'` to the if statement.  Hope it helps, or that someone comes up with a better method, because personally, I'd love to find a way to do this with just CSS.

---

### EDIT

Fixed JS code to use targetName.  Added support for icons.  Fixed codepen demo to match OP demo.

---

### EDIT 2

Found a cross browser error.  Fixed for Firefox by including event in the function parameters.

Comment: ahh would be easier if i just had all my pages on separate html pages rather than different divs on the same page..  tried that code and played around with it, but im not good when it comes to java :/

Comment: My bad, I provided bad code.  I was editing it from one of my recent projects (simplifying mostly) and removed something that I didn't fix.  I updated it and it should work as is now.

Comment: You sir.. Genius! I've spent all day trying to do this and you have solved my question perfectly

Comment: I made a few more adjustments and added the dismiss menu by clicking anywhere option to the [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGrrrB?editors=001).  Glad it works for you.  Still, it would be awesome to find a CSS version.

Comment: Realized I hadn't tested for cross browser support (it's javascript, why should I worry about that?).  Glad I tested.  Fixed the code for Firefox.  Apparently the event object is not passed in by default for Firefox, but is for ever other major browser (Chrome, IE11, Safari, and Opera...yes, I tested Opera).  Good to know this since I have been using this code and would have totally killed Firefox support.